# whose singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

I’ve just read this sentence;
„The one whose photos gets picked should quit“.

but I don’t understand, why the verb is in the singular, altough it refers to „photos“.

Comment: @Centaurus -- isn't _should quit_ the verb for _the one_?  That is, I parse it as _The one should quit._ / which one?  / the one _whose photos get picked_.  (Because it's _the photos_ that are getting picked, not _the one_.)  Am I missing something here?

Comment: No @RogerSinasohn   I'm the one who missed it.

Comment: “The one whose photos gets picked” is just ungrammatical—you shouldn’t waste time trying to understand the grammar of this sentence

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out sumelic, it was a brainfart on my part.